# По клику на баннер внутри iframe сделать скролл вниз

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Есть страница вверху которой iframe в который рекламодатель загружает баннер с рекламой. Внизу страницы находится div id="video" в котором видео в iframe. Как сделать чтобы по нажатии на этот баннер вверху, страница пользователя скроллировалась вниз до видео? Пробовал:

```
$(function() {
var scrollToAnchor = function() {
    var elem = $("#tabs_video");
    $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: elem.offset().top
    }, 1000 );
};
// bind to click event
 $(".js-scroll").click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        scrollToAnchor();
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```
$(".js-scroll").click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#tabs_video").position().top
    }, 1000 );
});
```